# redux-form FieldArray modifies props

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am trying to find a lib to use for my forms, to handle validation and stuff, and I come across redux-form which seems to be the most popular one.

There is one thing that troubles me with it though. In FieldArray example https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/examples/fieldarrays/ they modify props to add/remove fields. Isn't that actually anti-pattern which conflicts with functional programming principles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/fieldarray.md/

> **fields.push(value:Any) : Function**
>
> Adds a value to the end of the array. Returns nothing.
>
> This is not a mutator; it dispatches an action which updates the state in Redux, which will cause your component to rerender.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. One more thing. Do you know what's the best way to add new field based on some other form field? I have a case where I need to add it based on the number selected in the selector and from what I saw in the docs the only way to do it is to pass that prop to FieldArray component and then add fields in componentWillReceiveProps by mutating next props which I would like to avoid.

Comment: You could connect the component and use the [formValueSelector](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/)